# Find time average of hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, time

I have this fiddle that calculates average time with miliseconds. However, my DB stores data in format of hh:mm:ss.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/1/)

```
var times= [ '00:00:03.00', '00:00:05.00', '00:00:02.00', '00:00:06.00'],
    date = 0,
    result = '';
function offsetify(t){
    return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;
}
for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++ ) {
    var tarr = times[x].split(':');
    date += new Date(0, 0, 0, tarr[0], tarr[1], tarr[2].split('.')[0], tarr[2].split('.')[1]).getTime();   
}
var avg = new Date(date/times.length);
result = offsetify(avg.getHours()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getMinutes()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getSeconds()) + '.' + offsetify(avg.getMilliseconds());
document.write(result);
```

I need to make sure when seconds are averaged for example to 8.75 then average is returned as 00:00:9
using array like this:

```
var times= [ '00:00:03', '00:00:05', '00:00:020', '00:00:07']
```

can someone please help me modify this to properly round off hh:mm:ss format. thanks.

Comment: I think Nina's is a great answer, but want to ask -- when you say _"my DB stores data in format of hh:mm:ss"_ do you mean that you have a table which you are not allowed to alter that uses a `datetime` or `timestamp` field? ...because your DB certainly _could_ store average milliseconds as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the seconds, round the value and build a new string of the average time.

```js
function getAverageTime(array) {
    var times = [3600, 60, 1],
        parts = array.map(s => s.split(':').reduce((s, v, i) => s + times[i] * v, 0)),
        avg = Math.round(parts.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / parts.length);

    return times
        .map(t => [Math.floor(avg / t), avg %= t][0])
        .map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, 0))
        .join(':');
}

console.log(getAverageTime(['00:00:03', '00:00:05', '00:00:020', '00:00:07']));
console.log(getAverageTime(['00:00:03', '00:30:05', '00:30:020', '03:00:07']));
```

ES5

```js
function getAverageTime(array) {
    var times = [3600, 60, 1],
        parts = array.map(function (s) {
            return s.split(':').reduce(function (s, v, i) {
                return s + times[i] * v;
            }, 0);
        }),
        avg = Math.round(parts.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0) / parts.length);

    return times
        .map(function (t) {
            var value = Math.floor(avg / t);
            avg %= t;
            return value;
        })
        .map(function (v) {
            return v.toString().padStart(2, 0);
         })
        .join(':');
}

console.log(getAverageTime(['00:00:03', '00:00:05', '00:00:020', '00:00:07']));
console.log(getAverageTime(['00:00:03', '00:30:05', '00:30:020', '03:00:07']));
```

Comment: interesting solution. will this work properly once there are minutes more than 0 to make sure properly rounds to hours... etc

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: I am having trouble adding your code to my code.. it doesn't like =>

Answer (score 0):

```
var seconds = avg.getMilliseconds() > 500 ? avg.getSeconds() + 1 : avg.getSeconds();

result = offsetify(avg.getHours()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getMinutes()) + ':' + 
offsetify(seconds);
```

Basically just checking to see if ms is more than 50, if it is can manually add one to seconds, if not leave seconds as is. Not sure if you wanted seconds to be offset as well.

Comment: thanks it worked well with seconds. I wonder if it will work properly with minutes..or if i need something similar for minutes,, can you plz review this and see if it works properly
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f206y79m/)

Comment: there is 1000 ms in 1 s, so wouldn't you want to test if it's greater than 500?

Comment: actually can you please revisit this...
I tried to average these values: 00:01:20, 00:00:40, 00:01:00, 00:00:09
result was given to me 00:00:48 instead of 00:00:47

Comment: Bingo Steven. thank you for that comment. You answered my question before I asked it. checking it >500 did the trick and i did get 00:00:47

Answer (score 0):

First, convert all times into their UNIX timestamps using `Date.getTime()`, producing an array, then average the results. example: ]

```js
let times = [
1551984787316,
1551984789662,
1551984790162,
1551984790730,
1551984791310
]


let average = ( values ) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for( let i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( values[i], 10 ); // base 10
  }

  return Math.floor( sum/values.length );
}

let avgTime = average( times );
let avgDate = new Date( avgTime );
console.log( avgDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` can be used to convert them to milliseconds :

```js
function averageTime(arr) {
    var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + +new Date('1970T' + b + 'Z'); }, 0);
    return new Date(sum / arr.length + 500).toJSON().slice(11, 19);
}

console.log( averageTime(['00:00:03.00', '00:00:05.00', '00:00:02.00', '00:00:06.00']) );
console.log( averageTime(['00:00:03', '00:00:05', '00:00:20', '00:00:07']) );
```