# Find sum of time in an array of time format hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, time

I have this code that works to find the sum properly for format hh:mm
I am having hard time converting this to format hh:mm:ss
Obviously everything should be rounded up correctly.

this is the format of the array i am looking for to work with but code obviously works only for ["00", "10"] as an example

```js
const array = [
  ["00", "00", "09"],
  ["00", "00", "09"],
  ["00", "00", "04"],
  ["00", "00", "02"],
  ["00", "00", "21"],
  ["00", "00", "14"],
  ["00", "00", "26"],
  ["00", "00", "02"],
  ["00", "00", "14"],
  ["00", "00", "10"],
  ["00", "00", "48"],
  ["00", "00", "12"],
  ["00", "00", "09"],
  ["00", "00", "09"]
]

var mins = 0;
var hrs = 0;

if (array == null) {
  mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]);
  hrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
  hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + hrs;
} else {
  $.each(array, function(key) {
    mins += Number(array[key][1]);
    hrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
    hrs += Number(array[key][0]) + hrs;
  });
}

console.log(mins, hrs)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`t1` and `t2` in this case are just 2 separate values to be added together then there is an array of bunch of these. Both should work right.

please help me add properly seconds in here too.

Comment: If you're dealing with time, have a look at moment.js - it has all the bits you need. https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but i am just asking to help me edit the code that i already have to work with seconds as well.. thanks

Comment: do you have some data in text form and the wanted result?

Comment: btw, it looks like the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55049727/1447675) without the average part.

Comment: just updated. thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the seconds add all values and build a new string of the sum.

```js
function sumTime(t1, t2, array = []) {
    var times = [3600, 60, 1],
        sum = [t1, t2, ...array]
            .map(s => s.split(':').reduce((s, v, i) => s + times[i] * v, 0))
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    return times
        .map(t => [Math.floor(sum / t), sum %= t][0])
        .map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, 0))
        .join(':');
}

console.log(sumTime("01:02:03", "04:57:57"));
console.log(sumTime("00:00:09", "00:00:09", ["00:00:04", "00:00:02", "00:00:21", "00:00:14", "00:00:26", "00:00:02", "00:00:14", "00:00:10", "00:00:48", "00:00:12", "00:00:09", "00:00:09"]));
```

ES5

```js
function sumTime(t1, t2, array) {
    var times = [3600, 60, 1],
        sum = [t1, t2].filter(Boolean).concat(array || [])
            .map(function (s) {
                return s
                    .split(':') // omit this line for splitted values ['02', '04', '45']
                    .reduce(function (s, v, i) {
                        return s + times[i] * v;
                    }, 0);
            })
            .reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

    return times
        .map(function (t) {
            var value = Math.floor(sum / t);
            sum %= t;
            return value;
        })
        .map(function (v) {
            return v.toString().padStart(2, 0);
         })
        .join(':');
}


console.log(sumTime("01:02:03", null));
console.log(sumTime(null, "04:57:57"));
console.log(sumTime(null, null, ["01:02:03", "04:57:57"]));
console.log(sumTime("00:00:09", "00:00:09", ["00:00:04", "00:00:02", "00:00:21", "00:00:14", "00:00:26", "00:00:02", "00:00:14", "00:00:10", "00:00:48", "00:00:12", "00:00:09", "00:00:09"]));
```

With splitted arrays.

```js
function sumTime(t1, t2, array) {
    var times = [3600, 60, 1],
        sum = [t1, t2].filter(Boolean).concat(array || [])
            .map(function (s) {
                return s
                    //.split(':') // omit this line for splitted values ['02', '04', '45']
                    .reduce(function (s, v, i) {
                        return s + times[i] * v;
                    }, 0);
            })
            .reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

    return times
        .map(function (t) {
            var value = Math.floor(sum / t);
            sum %= t;
            return value;
        })
        .map(function (v) {
            return v.toString().padStart(2, 0);
         })
        .join(':');
}

console.log(sumTime(["01", "02", "03"], null));
console.log(sumTime(null, ["04", "57", "57"]));
console.log(sumTime(null, null, [["01", "02", "03"], ["04", "57", "57"]]));
console.log(sumTime(["00", "00", "09"], ["00", "00", "09"], [["00", "00", "04"], ["00", "00", "02"], ["00", "00", "21"], ["00", "00", "14"], ["00", "00", "26"], ["00", "00", "02"], ["00", "00", "14"], ["00", "00", "10"], ["00", "00", "48"], ["00", "00", "12"], ["00", "00", "09"], ["00", "00", "09"]]));
```

Comment: can you please convert this into similar code but without =>

Comment: and make sure it works for array and separate t1 and t2 values. Your code for average worked great.
so function would be function sumTime(t1, t2, array)
and if array is empty then use values from t1 and t2

Comment: that is `t1` abd `t2`?

Comment: also...format that i pass the array in is in the description. .. i don't need to split anymore.. it is already split ["00", "00", "09"],
so this array of 0 is hours, of 1 is min and of 2 is seconds

Comment: then omit `split(':')`.

Comment: can you please rewrite this without => I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: thank you for being so responsive.. not sure if it really works ...
sometimes i do pass in t1 and t2.. in those cases array is null
and sometimes i pass t1 and t2 as null and in those cases array is present. 

I thikn this way it always assumes i am passing all the values?

Comment: you solution is sooo close. I am afraid i am just bad at communicating my situation here. Sorry.
so sometimes i can pass in (null, null, array)
and other times (t1, t2, null)

Comment: i took out the part for split and i get an error
s.reduce is not a function

Comment: `.map(function (s) {
                        return s
                            .reduce(function (s, v, i) {
                                return s + times[i] * v;
                            }, 0);
                    })`

Comment: when i remove split... s comes back as "00" as i assume it's first part for hour

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comments mentioned, `moment` is a popular npm package for dealing with time. You can parse the times in your array data structure using the [formatting options](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) of moment:

```
const array = [
  [0, 0, 9],
  [0, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
   ...
];

const dates = array.map((date) => {
  return moment(`${date[0]}-${date[1]}-${date[2]}`, 'hh-mm-ss');
  // make sure you account for 12 or 24 hour clocks, not sure which you are using
});

const sum = dates.reduce((date, total) => { return total.add(date); }, moment.duration(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly the same math, just applied one more time for seconds -> minutes.

```
seconds = t1[2] + t2[2];
mins = parseInt(seconds / 60);
seconds = seconds % 60;
mins += t1[1] + t2[1];
hrs = parseInt(minutes / 60);
mins = mins % 60;
hrs += t1[0] + t2[0];
```

I'm assuming you already know how to convert `hh:mm:ss` to an appropriate array by simply using `split` and `Number`, but just in case:

```
t1 = time1.split(':').map(part => Number(part));
t2 = time2.split(':').map(part => Number(part));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **reducer** function to total the corresponding array elements and then amend the result.

```js
var timeArrays = [
  ['00', '52', '00'],
  ['00', '08', '00'],
  ['00', '00', '40'],
  ['00', '00', '01'],
  ['00', '00', '20']
];

function totalTimeAsString(timeArray) {
  var result = ['00', '00', '00'];

  var reducer = function(acc, current) {
    return [
      Number(acc[0]) + Number(current[0]),
      Number(acc[1]) + Number(current[1]),
      Number(acc[2]) + Number(current[2])
    ];
  };

  var [hh, mm, ss] = timeArray.reduce(reducer, result);

  // seconds
  if (ss > 59) {
    mm += Math.floor(ss / 60);
  }
  ss = ss % 60;
  result[2] = ((ss < 10) ? '0' : '') + ss;

  // minutes
  if (mm > 59) {
    hh += Math.floor(mm / 60);
  }
  mm = mm % 60;
  result[1] = ((mm < 10) ? '0' : '') + mm;

  // hours
  result[0] = ((hh < 10) ? '0' : '') + hh;

  return result.join(':');
}

console.log(totalTimeAsString(timeArrays));
// "01:01:01"
```